# Display location permission dialog when application opens for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display location permission dialog when application is opened (I retrieve the actual location later). Can I just pretend to retrieve location by doing the following:

```
    if(firstApplicationLaunch){
       firstApplicationLaunch = NO;
       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
       [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

Comment: From your question it sounds like you haven't even tried it to see if it works. Go try to solve the problem yourself first, then if you don't find a solution post what you tried here.

Comment: I think he's asking if this is the best way to force the dialog, not if the code itself works. Which seems like a valid question.

Comment: @RayanR Joel is correct, I tried the code and its working but I want to make sure if this is the best way or if I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will force the location permission dialog on launch. However, you'll need to be careful not to release `CLLocationManager` or let it go out of scope before the user responds to the dialog otherwise the dialog will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it looks like if you try to access [CLLocationManager location] the dialog will not be displayed (coz it will only cache the location if you start updating location).

Comment: That's odd. The documentation is vague enough that it sounded like any access to location services would do it. So what you have in your question is the way to go.

Comment: Just be sure locationManager doesn't go out of scope or you will lose the dialog without an answer.

Comment: Good point. If you want to update your answer, I could mark it as accepted.